# Intercepting and updating the product weight and dimensions for UPS shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce and the UPS shipping plugin.  I have a custom product which has user selectable dimensions and then the weight is calculated based on the user dimensions.  I can't seem to find where, if it's possible, I can intercept the shipping calculations when I add the item to the cart.  Where can I find this functionality?  Also, is this the proper way to store the additional information in the database?

I currently save the information into the cart item as follows:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'rs_add_cart_item', 10, 1);
function rs_add_cart_item($cart_item) {
    echo 'rs_add_cart_item(cart_item)';
    echo '<pre>';
    $cart_item['data']->width = 14;
    $cart_item['data']->height = 15;
    $cart_item['data']->length = 16;
    $cart_item['data']->weight = 23.456;
    print_r($cart_item['data']);
    echo '</pre>';

    return $cart_item;
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Measurement Price Calculator](www.woothemes.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/)?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the MPC early on and decided it wouldn't work in this case.  It just allows the customer to enter say room dimensions and then calculates the number of boxes of precut and boxed tiles you would need.  Each box of tiles would have set dimensions and weights.  I, literally calculate the product weight from user input dimensions from 6 to 100 inches per side.  E.g., 20 custom prints that are 24x35 inches and 0.1 pound each.  I then need to feed the dimensions and weight to the UPS shipping plugin.

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess I completely misunderstood what MPC does.